# R markdown with Beamer: table too wide

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, beamer

I've been trying for ages to find a way to get my table to shrink enough to fit on a slide. The base code looks like:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: beamer_presentation
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
```

## Table

The table below is too long.

```{r}
kable(summary(mtcars), format = "latex") 
```
````

If I try adding `%>% kable_styling(full_width = TRUE)` or anything like that, I get this error:
`! LaTeX Error: Environment tabu undefined.`. But I don't get it when I change the `output` to `pdf_document`.

Is there anyway to make tables that are too wide fit into a beamer presentation? Or will I always be limited to about 5/6 columns?

Answer (score 0):

For your specific task, I think you should use `kable_styling(latex_options = "scale_down").

===

If you want to use other features in kableExtra, put the following things in your yaml header. You can find some extra explanation at the very beginning (on Page 2 right now) of the package manual(http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf).

```
header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{colortbl}
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{tabu}
- \usepackage{threeparttable}
```